# How does a syncadapter delete data on the local db

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I just had a little confusion about how a sync provider utilizes delete. After reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#Delete, I implemented my own custom content provider, and I've written the server side implementation so that all the rows with the deleted flag set are deleted on the server, but when do the rows get deleted off the device? I wrote the rest of the application so that only rows without the delete flag are ever used, but are rows that are deleted simply left there and never deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious, I simply ended up writing my ContentProvider such that it does not query for rows with the deleted flag set unless specifically queried for. This includes the other REST methods. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but it works.